# Count years of increasing profits

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to count how many years a company has increased the profit from now. So if the previous year had lower profits than this year it counts as 1 and goes one year back in past to count until there is one years profit higher than the year after that. So it must be a ongoing trend from this year (2017) so that it counts the years.

[image: See here]

**(Years of increases should be 5 not 4, sorry!)**

In the picture it has to count until 2011 because there was a year(2012) without increasing profits relative to last year(2011).

So maybe its even possible with a Excel Function. Otherwise VBA is probably the way to do this.

EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: I dont understand your question. It should be 5 right because there were 5 years with an increased profit compared to the previous year. Or are you talking about a streak?

Comment: What is the right answer in your example? Can you provide more examples? It's not clear at this moment.

Comment: the answer would be 6 not 4, since there is only one year it decreased year over year

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It should find out the streak of increasing years. So its like a quality criteria to see how well a company is doing at its business. So if there is one interruption then everything before is irrelevant.
But yeah, it should be 5 years of increases. Because from -3 to 2 is an increase however in 2011 there was a higher profit.

Comment: EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: Hey, I just found a fundamental thing that should be changed in the formula.
If the profits are 0 - 0 - 0 - 0. It shouldnt count steady profits. How to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: formula for the better explained requirements in comments (see previous versions in history):

```
=COLUMN(I2) - MAX(($C2:I2 < $B2:H2) * COLUMN($C2:I2), COLUMN($B2))
```

Comment: This looks to be the simplified version of the approach that I suggested. But I hope you also assumed anything positive is considered as profit and it only considers that. If you put year 2014 profit as 5, it will still show five, where as as per question, it has to be 1

Comment: @Karpak it's developed independently, but in my explicitly written 1st assumption the meaning of `5` is that profit was 5 higher than last year. I added the 2nd option if the data means plain "profit" and not already pre-calculated diff

Comment: @pnuts oh well, 0 is unspecified in the question, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, but thanks for pointing that out - I changed `<` to `<=` for consistency in both interpretations

Comment: yeah the data is the absolute profit of every year.

Comment: the second formula gives me 6 if there is a complete streak (7 increases) So it doesnt count 2010 if there is an increase to 2011. If there is an interruption before then it works, but not if all years have increasing profits.

Comment: EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: Hey, I just found a fundamental thing that should be changed in the formula.
If the profits are 0 - 0 - 0 - 0. It shouldnt count steady profits. How to do something like that?

Comment: and how to add a dynamic change that if there is no data yet for actual year(2017) that it just calculates from/until 2016?

Comment: that might be better posted as a new question, hard for me to test additional ideas on a phone during vacation

Comment: hmm, maybe now? :D here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423092/how-to-count-increasing-profit-streak

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the streak of *"increased/same profit"* starting from current year, try the below formulas in the 2<sup>nd</sup> row:

 - in cell K2: `=IF(B2>=A2,1,0)`

 - in cell S2: `=IF(K2=1,A4+K2,K2)`

 - in cell J2: `=Z2`

then copy the cell `K2` to the range `L2:R2`, cell `S2` to the range `T2:Z2`, and then copy the range `J2:Z2` to all the applicable rows as per below pic.

[image]

Note: instead of filling-up with formulas in rows 3 & 4, sure it can be done directly in cell `J2` by way of [Excel array](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), but for the sake of simplicity this method is preferable.

Edit: the above post was updated as per subsequent discussion with @technotoast to make the following adjustments:

 - there are many companies in the list - not just "Apple"

 - the streak will continue for same profit levels also - not just increasing profit

Comment: @curious, I assume by "streak of increased profit" you mean the longest span of years in which profit increased from the previous year. The formulae in rows 3 and 4 are fine but you are assuming that the data will **always** be such that the streak ends in column I. If the value in cell I2 was, say, 5 rather than 7, the "streak of increased profit" would only be 4 years long. The values in cell I3, I4 and J2 would now all be 0, so not showing the correct result. A formula such as `=MAX(B4:I4)` in cell J2 would not require your assumption.

Comment: hi @DMM the question is "to count how many years a company has increased the profit from now". so it's not the longest streak, rather the streak if any, as of the current year

Comment: Yeah, if the current year is lower than previous year, then there is streak of 0.
But the problem is, I want to to this with the next 4000 companies under that row, too. So It should be filled by a vba macro or should be a single cell formula.

Comment: How do I make this an excel array formula? 
EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: if there are other companies below that list, just move row 3 & 4 to row 2 right after column J. for excel array i have already provided the link & other answers provided solutions based on array. if you want to include steady profit too, just change the `>` to `>=`. i have update the answer accordingly. hope this helps:)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see an easy way of doing this other than by working backwards through the year using an offset of 0, -1, -2 etc. from the last one and searching for the first instance where the profit for the later year is not greater than the profit for the earlier year. If there is no such instance, then all years show an increasing profit.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE,N(OFFSET($I2,0,COLUMN($B2)-COLUMN($B2:$H2),1,1))>N(OFFSET($H2,0,COLUMN($B2)-COLUMN($B2:$H2),1,1)),0)-1,"All in profit")
```

This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Well I thought it would be interesting to find a way of going backwards through the arrays, but looking at this objectively, I would say that the other two answers are probably more useful :-)

Comment: Awesome method, too. Thanks!
EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: Yes, it should just be changing > to >=

Comment: Hey, I just found a fundamental thing that should be changed in the formula.
If the profits are 0 - 0 - 0 - 0. It shouldnt count steady profits. How to do something like that?

Comment: and how to add a dynamic change that if there is no data yet for actual year(2017) that it just calculates from/until 2016?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below array formula, if you are looking for number of time the profit is increased starting from current year. Enter the below formula and press Shift+Control+Enter. The last -1 is to align this with your answer. If you want 5 instead of four, you can remove that -1.

```
=COUNT(B2:H2)-MAX(IF(C2:I2<B2:H2,COLUMN(C2:I2)-COLUMN(B2)))
```

by using this, with only one formula you can achieve what you want.

Comment: mmm, No, it is based on the question, if the current year profit is more than previous year profit, then only it has to count 1, otherwise, it shouldn't count. it is based on that.

Comment: you are using `-2` as a constant, but `COUNT(C2:I2)` as calculated non-constant... this will stop working if the data will start at different column than `B` (I removed my previous comment about assumptions and tried to explain that better in my answer)

Comment: @pnuts, I understand your point. However, OP has to answer what is expected here. May be based on his answer, it may require some change in this formula

Comment: @pnuts, Well, its a learning for me, not to answer such a Q in SO:), however my intent was to give some thought process to the OP to find an answer him/her self and I didn't want to assume anything on the OPs post

Comment: If the 2017's profits would be 0  (or something else lower than 2016) then there should be a streak of 0.

Comment: if that is the case, the =IF((COUNT(C2:I2)-1-MAX(IF(B2:H2<C2:I2=FALSE,COLUMN(C2:I2)-COLUMN(B2))))<0,0,COUNT(C2:I2)-1-MAX(IF(B2:H2<C2:I2=FALSE,COLUMN(C2:I2)-COLUMN(B2)))) formula give you the answer what you wanted.

Comment: EDIT: Is it possible to count years of steady profits, too? Like if 2015 = 5 and 2016 = 5 then this should not stop streak.

Comment: Yes, It should be possible, if you make the < as <=

Comment: the first formula gives me 6 if there is a complete streak (7 increases) So it doesnt count 2010 if there is an increase to 2011. If there is an interruption before then it works, but not if all years have increasing profits. The second formula seems to not even work for me at all.

Comment: Can you give me the example of what is that you expect in each of the category with data?

Comment: 2010-2017 is filled with 1-8 and then "years of increases" should be 7 because every year has a higher profit than previous year.

Comment: =COUNT(B2:H2)-MAX(IF(C2:I2<B2:H2,COLUMN(C2:I2)-COLUMN(B2))) as array formula will give you that result. Edited the answer as well.

Comment: Hey, I just found a fundamental thing that should be changed in the formula.
If the profits are 0 - 0 - 0 - 0. It shouldnt count steady profits. How to do something like that?

Comment: and how to add a dynamic change that if there is no data yet for actual year(2017) that it just calculates from/until 2016?